# HandsOnTable Chrome Bug with DatePicker

Tags: google-chrome, handsontable

I seemed to have found a bug when selecting dates running Chrome with HandsOnTable versions later than 15.1.

I'm able to drop down the calendar but I'm unable to select a day within the calendar control.  This is only a problem for me in Chrome as it seems to work fine in Firefox, IE and Edge.

After further research this bug only occurs on a touchscreen enabled device but the user is using a mouse.

Here is a screen capture video of the behavior straight from www.handsontable.com website:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEdiWQ5R5Es

GitHub Issue Thread: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2812

Let me know if anyone else can reproduce this behavior and if there is workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a better solution in my opinion.  This will register both events separately so these events will work on all devices.

https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues/374

Thanks for the step in the right direction.  Hopefully Pickaday and HandsOnTable can incorporate the change soon.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. Maybe this can help you. I did for me.
Currently I'm working with **handsontable.full.js** (version  0.18.0) and

I changed line 24550

addEvent(self.el, 'ontouchend' in document ? 'touchend' : 'mousedown', self._onMouseDown, true);

to

addEvent(self.el, 'mousedown', self._onMouseDown, true);

I took it from
https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues/276

Hope that helps.
Good luck